# Why has my tiff file converted to jpeg and shrunk to almost nothing

Tags: image-quality, printing, jpeg, tiff, file-size

i recently had a photograph of my art taken by a photography studio and the file size was huge, over 100mb. Here are the details of that [image: image details]

I then cropped the image myself so it could be used for greetings cards, the image dropped in size again which I knew would happen and it dropped to 86mb. As I need to print this image, I have had to send this file via wetransfer so it can be printed. I noticed that when I sent the file on we transfer the image size went from 86mb to less than 500kb. I have no idea why this has happened. When I downloaded the photo I sent them ( to check the quality to make sure nothing was lost ) pixel size remains the same, dpi is at 511 (according to my MacBook when looking at the file info) it’s just the file size that’s changed. Does anyone know why the file size has changed and will it have any effect on the print? I’ve also noticed it’s changed from being a tiff file to JPEG.I’m so confused lol!
Here is the wetransfer download image data
[image]

Comment: I've closed this question because these are clearly not the same image - they have different filenames and pixel counts. Happy to reopen it if/when the information is corrected.

Comment: @PhilipKendall they have different pixel counts because the OP said that he/she cropped it. The differing filenames are suspicious though.

Comment: @CD4765145242 WeTransfer won't convert a TIFF file to a JPEG, but something else you have done must have done this. What application did you use to crop your photo, and how did you save/export the photo out of this application? I believe that's where/when the format conversation would have occurred.

Answer (score 2):

There are few points:

1. If there is some compression in TIFF it is lossless, in JPEG it is lossy. So depend of the level of compression you can make much smaller file
2. Seems like you strip all the meta information when creating JPEG. In some cases this can make significant difference in size
3. And last you crop the image so this also decrease the size of image.

P.S. Based on the image name you show meta information for different images.